# Select text from keyboard in matlab

Tags: matlab, emacs

In emacs, it's possible to set a mark with `c-space`. The mark marks one end of a selection then when you move the cursor the other end of the selection moves with it.

For example, `c-a, c-space, c-n, c-n` selects two lines of text.

Matlab doesn't seem to have the concept of placing a mark. Is there any way to select text from the keyboard?

I'd like to do things like whack/yank a few words or comment out multiple lines without using the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I found this old question while trying to figure out the same problem. If anyone out there is still looking for how to do this, Matlab (as of version 2016a) supports keyboard selection shortcuts in the keyboard binding preferences (Preferences --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts). By default the text select functions are using the Home/End and Ctr/Shift + arrow keys to do this. I don't think the Emacs marking concept works but you could define a shortcut to your liking.

[Matlab Emacs Keyboard Binding Defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq8R8.png)

At least you don't have to use the mouse :-)